# Change state onClick React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, events, redux, pagination, onclick

How can I change value of currentPage state using onClick event? I would like to change value after click button with number of page.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setCurrentPage } from '../actions/pages';
const PageItem = ({ pageNumber }) => (
      <li className="page-link"
        onClick = {(e) => this.setCurrentPage(e) }
        id = { pageNumber }>
        { pageNumber }
      </li>
);
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    pages: state.pages.currentPage
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentPage: () => dispatch(setCurrentPage(pageNumber))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PageItem);
```

Reducer:

```
const pagesReducerDefaultState = { 
 currentPage: 1
};

export default (state = pagesReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_CURRENT_PAGE':
                return action.currentPage;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Action:

```
export const setCurrentPage = (currentPage) => ({
  type: 'SET_CURRENT_PAGE',
  currentPage
});
```

Comment: have you tried `return ({currentPage: action.currentPage})` in your Reducer?

Comment: Yes, but still does not work.

Comment: Setting the page onclick looks wrong, have you tried this?   `onClick = {() => this.setCurrentPage(pageNumber ) }`

Comment: I tried this and I get error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCurrentPage' of undefined
    at onClick (PageItem.js:7)

Comment: Remove `this` the method is imported ->  `onClick = {() => setCurrentPage(pageNumber ) }`

Comment: It is moving in the right direction. I set `console.log(currentPage)` in actions, and after click I see number of page in console corretly. But state of currentPage in debugger still shows crossed 1.

Comment: your mapDispatchToProps need some adjustment `setCurrentPage: pageNumber => dispatch(setCurrentPage(pageNumber))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed some of your errors.
To begin with, I suppose that you have made a `Provider` markup in your root Component and make an instance to a store (if you're not sure, send the content of the App.js file).

// component

```js
const PageItem = ({ pageNumber, setCurrentPage }) => (
  <li
    className="page-link"
    onClick={() => setCurrentPage(pageNumber)}
    id={pageNumber}
  >
    {pageNumber}
  </li>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    page: state.currentPage
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setCurrentPage
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(PageItem);

const pagesReducerDefaultState = {
  currentPage: 1
};
```

Some thoughts :

- you can't use `this` in a function, only in a class
- `mapDispatchToProps` may be used with a simple litteral object (like [I learned it recently](https://daveceddia.com/redux-mapdispatchtoprops-object-form/)). This is less verbose then, because you may only mention the `action creator` (in your example, `setCurrentPage`)
- you have send `setCurrentPage` in the props, so you can retrieve it like I wrote. Maybe ES6 is cryptic here, so the ES5 equivalent will be:

```js
function PageItem(props) {
  return (
    <li
      className="page-link"
      onClick={() => props.setCurrentPage(props.pageNumber)}
      id={props.pageNumber}
    >
      {props.pageNumber}
    </li>
  );

};
```

// reducer

```js
const initialState = {
  currentPage: 1
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_CURRENT_PAGE":
      return {
        currentPage: action.currentPage
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

- your state is an object with a property `currentPage`. So your reducer must return this kind of object (so `return action.currentPage` was not correct)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I also readed your article and it was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your action like below. Action should be dispatched so that reducer can handle it..

```
export const setCurrentPage = (currentPage) => {
 return (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({type: 'SET_CURRENT_PAGE',currentPage);
 }
}
```