# Variable value doesn't update in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using an onClick handler in a stateless React Component. 
When a click event is triggered on a div, it fires the `loadMore` action who uses a redux action to fetch more data from a REST API.

```
count = 6;

var loadMore = e => {
 getArticlesComments(article.slug, count, count + 2);
 count = count + 6;
};
```

My issue is that `count` isn't updating because of the redux action. If I remove it, `count` is updating properly.

Why a redux action (which is correctly working) stops `count` from updating ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your **count** into state and then update a state

Answer (score 0):

React only reacts to updates on your state or props. From the code you have shared, it does not seem like `count` is part of any state. If you want your view to update when count changes, then count needs to be within a state. You mentioned that your component is stateless so you either need to:

1. Convert your component to a regular component and define `state = { count: 0}` and update it with `setState` in your 'loadMore' event. [See example](https://learn.co/lessons/react-updating-state)
2. Move count to your redux state and map it to a property using mapStateToProps and, finally, update count via your redux reducer and not in your 'loadMore' event. See [updating state in redux](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/#how-to-update-state-in-redux)

Edit: a better example for #2 [Change state onClick React+Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699936/change-state-onclick-reactredux)